# inline-block - how to show all one one line?

Tags: css, overflow

First of all - here is what I'm trying to achieve. I have a filters bar in my new design. On this bar, there are 10 or so items. As the page gets smaller, not all of these items can be shown (due to width restrictions). I have a "more filters" button option, that opens it up so people can see all the filter options. Anyway, that is just some background.

Currently I have a wrapper div, and then div's within that for each filter. Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pw0bum2x/

I'm aware I can use the `overflow: hidden` to hide the content flowing outside of the filters div - BUT that causes me other issues (the filters are custom dropdown elements, and because they are inside the div with overflow being hidden, they then don't show up properly (gets cut off outside the parent div)

So here is my CSS:

```
.filters {
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
}   

.sub-filter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

...and then HTML:

```
<div class="filters">

    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 1
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 2
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 3
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 4
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 5
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 6
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 7
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 8
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 9
    </div>
    <div class="sub-filter">
        test 10
    </div>

</div>
```

So I guess really what I'm asking for, is how can I make all of those elements stay on one line (so that I can use `overflow-x:hidden` to hide it, instead of the `overflow: hidden`, which causes me issues with the *y-axis*)

Please ask if you need any more clarification. Hopefully I've explained it well enough :)

**UPDATE:** OK, so it seems there isn't really a good solution to what I'm trying to do. While some of the ideas work to an extent, they don't work for how I need to implement it. Very frustrating. What I think I'm going to do, is go for a JS feature. Basically hide all the items, and then use jQuery to grab the width of the filters bar, and apply a "**show**" class to the ones I want to show (and will fit)

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/pw0bum2x/1/

Comment: @Designer - am I missing something? Looks the same?

Comment: Check the edited link on my comment @Andrew Newby

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` to `.filters`.

So it will become:

```css
.filters {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
} 

.sub-filter {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">

 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 1
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 2
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 3
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 4
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 5
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 6
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 7
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 8
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 9
 </div>
 <div class="sub-filter">
  test 10
 </div>
 

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but that causes a horizontal scrollbar - I don't want any scrollbars :) I want it all on one line, but hiding the elements that don't fit

Comment: Could you just change `overflow-x: scroll;` to overflow-x: hidden; I've updated my answer with this.

Comment: thanks, the problem I then get is what happens if the bar doesn't fit exactly: https://ibb.co/krFjTb

Answer (score 0):

You're able to use `display:flex`. If you attach this to your `.filters`, the child will sit on a line.

See https://jsfiddle.net/rqbjjmxy/ for the example.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, that squishes it all up though. It needs to just hide the filters sections that won't fit